# Whats the time and space complexity of this code to find a cycle in a Directed graph using dfs iterative

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
    public boolean cycleInGraph(int[][] edges) {
        // Write your code here.
        int n = edges.length;
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];

        Arrays.fill(visited, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (visited[i]) continue;

            boolean containsCycle =
                helper(edges, i, visited);
            if (containsCycle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean helper(int[][] edges, int i, boolean[] visited) {
        Set < Integer > set = new HashSet < > ();
        Stack < Map.Entry < Integer, Set < Integer >>> s = new Stack < > ();
        set.add(i);
        s.push(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry < > (i, set));

        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            Map.Entry < Integer, Set < Integer >> curr = s.pop();
            Set < Integer > path = curr.getValue();
            int node = curr.getKey();
            visited[node] = true;
            if (edges[node].length == 0) path.remove(node);
            for (int children: edges[node]) {
                if (visited[children] && path.contains(children)) {
                    return true;
                }
                Set < Integer > temp = new HashSet < > (path);
                temp.add(children);
                s.push(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry < > (children, temp));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please confirm is the time and space complexity is O(V+E) and O(V) ?

I used a iterative dfs using a stack and storing the path in the stack.

What I want to understand is the space used at any point is O(V).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the space complexity is not O(). For a given starting node `i`, the helper function stores for each of its (non-cyclic) descendants the path from `i` to that descendant. In a worst case this could represent O(²).

Take for instance this graph:

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
      / \
     4   5
        / \
       6   7
          / \
         8   ...
             ...
             /  \
          -1
```

...and let `i` be the root node. Then the loop will add two nodes to the stack in each iteration, and pop one, until it reaches node . When it has arrived there, we have a stack with /2 entries (representing the nodes with *even* numbers), and each will have a set with the nodes on the root-to-node path. So the sizes of those sets are 2, 3, 4, 5, ... /2

```
  <2, {1, 2}>
  <4, {1, 3, 4}>
  <6, {1, 3, 5, 6}>
  <8, {1, 3, 5, 7, 8}>
   ...
```

The sum of these set sizes is a triangular number and is O(²).

As the creation of a set of size  has a time complexity of O() (see the statement where `temp` is assigned), you also have a worst-case time complexity of O(²) = O(²).

Comment: But in the example you mentioned, we pop 1, 2,3 before going to 4.
At any point it is O(V) right?

Comment: Yes, my example was not a worst case. Updated to give a worst case example.

Comment: yes you are right, thanks for clarifying.

Do you know what can be done to have O(V+E) time and O(V) to achieve this iteratively?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to use one more state (apart from `visited`) for each node, indicating whether you have finished visiting all of a node's descendants. A cycle is found when the current node was already visited, but not yet "finished". You don't need to stack any sets then. If you get stuck implementing that idea, you may ask a new question about that including your code attempt and problem description.

Comment: Got it, like have an another visited array for each traversal, like currVisited.